# ENCLOSED BY error whilst using PHP CSV import script

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have CSV file that needs importing to a MySQL database. I am using a PHP script to import the CSV.

The script works fine until I add an ENCLOSED BY statement, the reason I am adding that statement is because one of the values in the CSV column contains text with commas however the value is wrapped by quotation marks.

Here is an example of the CSV column that contains the value wrapped in quotation marks:

,"1 Registered Keeper, Full Service History, Central Locking, Electric Windows, Electric Mirrors, ABS, Traction Control, Climate Control, Power Steering, Drivers Airbag, Passenger Airbag, Side Airbags, Cruise Control, Alarm, Immobiliser, Half Leather Interior, Alloy Wheels",

Here is the script I have tried to get working:

```
<?php
$databasehost = "localhost"; 
$databasename = "import"; 
$databasetable = "import"; 
$databaseusername="import"; 
$databasepassword = "password"; 
$fieldseparator = ","; 
$lineseparator = "\n";
$enclosedbyquote = '"';
$csvfile = "test.csv";

if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
    die("File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.");
}

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename", 
        $databaseusername, $databasepassword,
        array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        )
    );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage());
}

$pdo->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE `$databasetable`");

    $affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." REPLACE INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
    ENCLOSED BY ".$pdo->quote($enclosedbyquote)."
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)." 
    LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator)." 
    IGNORE 1 LINES");

echo "Loaded a total of $affectedRows records from this csv file.\n";

?>
```

Since I have added:

```
$enclosedbyquote = '"';
```

And

```
ENCLOSED BY ".$pdo->quote($enclosedbyquote)."
```

I get an error :(

Any idea what I am doing wrong, any tips would be much appreciated!?

Comment: Not all fields are enclosed, so you should use ´OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY´ instead.

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). You need tu put `FIELDS` word first.

Instead of

```
ENCLOSED BY ".$pdo->quote($enclosedbyquote)."
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
```

you should have:

```
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY ".$pdo->quote($enclosedbyquote)."
     TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
```

Comment: I am now left with this error :(

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\"'' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 2' in /home/dealerby/public_html/driven_import.php:35 Stack trace: #0 /home/dealerby/public_html/driven_import.php(35): PDO->exec('??LOAD DATA LOC...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/dealerby/public_html/driven_import.php on line 35

Comment: So what's your query now? Have you removed `enclosed by` ? I don't see it in this query

Comment: I am using this query:

$affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." REPLACE INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
 FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ".$pdo->quote($enclosedbyquote)."
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)." 
 LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator)." 
 IGNORE 1 LINES");

Comment: Don't use `FIELDS` 2 times. They should be only used one time as `FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ...  TERMINATED BY ...` and not `FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ...  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ...`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing quotes arround your enclosed by char:

```
ENCLOSED BY '".$pdo->quote($enclosedbyquote)."'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html